# Use data from view in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, view

I was wondering if it's possible to use data from the view in my javascript code? This is what I have:

View "**index.phtml**":

```
<?php $event = $this->event; ?>
<script>
     // HERE I WANT TO USE $event
     var data = <?=$event?>;
</script>
```

But that doesn't work!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it contain a string value:

```
<script>
var data = '<?php echo $event; ?>';
</script>
```

If it contain a numeric value:

```
<script>
var data = <?php echo $event; ?>;
</script>
```

Also `php` short tag `<?=` should be `On` in `php.ini` to use it.